# Fail to transmit data from JS to Webview with addJavascriptInterface

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to entry a webpage in android webview .At the same time, the server transmit some data to me.
In JS:

```js
function callAndroidApp(){
         try {
           wv.PostDataFromWebToWebView('".$msg."');
       } catch(err) {
        console.log('The android context does not exist yet');
       }
   }
callAndroidApp();
```

in java：

```
public class webview extends AppCompatActivity {

@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    WebView webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this,"wv" );
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);  //关键点
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // 设置显示缩放按钮
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://health.sjtu.edu.cn");
    webView.requestFocusFromTouch();       //支持获取手势焦点

    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    String ua=webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua+";sjtu-android");

}
@JavascriptInterface
public void PostDataFromWebToWebView(String msg){
    parseJSONWithJSONObject(msg);
}
public void parseJSONWithJSONObject(String msg2){
    try{
        JSONObject jsonData=new JSONObject(msg2);
        String userid=jsonData.getString("userid");
        String action=jsonData.getString("action");
        String name=jsonData.getString("name");
        String jaccount=jsonData.getString("jaccount");
        String token=jsonData.getString("token");
        URL url=new URL("https://health.sjtu.edu.cn/post-data-from-app.php?jaccount="+jaccount+"&userid="+userid+"&token="+token+"&CMD=current_steps&steps="+1234);
        Log.v("webhttpsrequest",url.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**sometimes especially the first time,it worked .But always it failed.
The Logcat shows as follows:**

05-05 10:43:13.041 10871-10909/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/OpenGLRenderer: PerfServiceNative_notifyRenderTime init fail!
05-05 10:43:23.026 10871-10871/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
05-05 10:43:23.048 10871-10871/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
05-05 10:43:23.048 10871-10871/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
05-05 10:43:23.078 10871-10871/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
05-05 10:43:23.093 10871-10871/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
05-05 10:43:23.247 10871-10909/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f82891200
05-05 10:43:25.402 10871-10871/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_autofill_client.cc(175)] Not implemented reached in virtual void android_webview::AwAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
05-05 10:43:28.199 10871-10909/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f7465c340
05-05 10:43:31.467 10871-10909/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f7465c340
05-05 10:56:56.360 10871-10909/com.step.pedometer.mystep E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f74659140